# Finding dimension of Quotient Space without using formula

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V be the 3 dimensional vector space with basis (1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1) and W be a subspace with basis (1,0,0)(1,1,0). Find the dimension of quotient space V/W without using dim(V/W)=dim(V) - dim(W)

What is the physical significance of quotient space or how can you visualise quotient space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, it’s relatively easy. Your subspace $W$ is just a plane, and the quotient space is just the collection of all planes in $V$ parallel to $W$. Think of a stack of sheets of paper

Comment: I understand this. If V/W is a plane, its dimension is 2. Even W is a plane. Its dimenison is also 2. Dimension of V is 3. If all these statements are true then the formula stated in my question doesnt add up. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: No. Think of the stack of sheets. That’s just a one-parameter family, right? You measure how far a sheet is from the central sheet by just one number, right? So $V/W$ is one-dimensional.